# Is there a pattern for concurrent searching?

Tags: multithreading, search, design-patterns

I have this concurrent pattern that came up when trying to model my problem, and I don't know if there's a name for it. Having a design pattern reference or something like that could help me implement it more safely.

**Concept:**
The foreman (main thread) is asked to look for a series of objects in a big warehouse.
This warehouse has `n` floors. The foreman has a team of `n` workers (helper threads), each with a dedicated floor.
The foreman recieves an object, and asks every worker to find it.
If a worker finds it on their floor, they return to the foreman with appropriate information. (location, status...)
The foreman then calls back all other workers (since the item has been found there's no need for more searching), and move on to the next object.
If everyone comes back saying "No it's not on my floor" we can act accordingly. (signal a missing product to management...)

The main problem I have is that I need to make sure threads don't waste calculation time when the item has already been found, and to ensure proper coordination.
I also can't give every thread the entire list of things to find, since this information is recieved item by item. (eg. via network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for Observer pattern ?
Once a worker finds the item and returns to the Foreman. The Foreman should notify to all the workers that the item is found, so all the threads will stop search and return.